# Bash how to pass environment for a command within script

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

So I have a python script that needs locale defined in environment variable like so: `export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`. So I thought that I would simply create a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8   
sudo python3 example.py
```

But the python script complains that the environment variable is not set properly. When I run these commands manually or export the environment variable before executing the script, the program works. There must be some sort of catch here that I'm missing.

Comment: I think this question was better asked on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: or superuser. Specifically, [how do I make sudo preserve my environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in theory you are doing it correctly:
environnment variables that are marked with `export` will be exported to child-processes (that is: programs started from this shell).

However.

`sudo` is a bit different, as it is highly security sensitive.
After all, you could change the behaviour of a command running with superuser-powers *completely*, if you used the right variables (think `LD_PRELOAD`).

Therefore `sudo` actively prevents environment-variables to be passed to sudoed processes.

Luckily (for you), you can change which env-vars are preserved (at least, if the system's security policy allows it).

From `man 8 sudo`:

```
     -E, --preserve-env
                 Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve
                 their existing environment variables.  The security policy may
                 return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve
                 the environment.

     --preserve-env=list
                 Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to add the
                 comma-separated list of environment variables to those preserved
                 from the user's environment.  The security policy may return an
                 error if the user does not have permission to preserve the
                 environment.  This option may be specified multiple times.
```

Comment: So if I'm only interested about this LC_ALL value, then `sudo --preserve-env=LC_ALL python3 example.py` should be enought?

Comment: yes. (but it's **really** easy to just try this out)